# How to prevent UIImageView touches method while UITableView is scrolling?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, touches

I take one `UITableView` and in that `UITableview` I have a `UImageView` in the cells. I do one operation when click on `UIImageView`.
Now problem is that whenever I scroll the `UITableView` that touch method of `UIImageView` is called.
I want to prevent that touch method when I scroll the `UITableView`.

Thnx in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The method which you are using to detect imageView's tap, in that method you can just add following code:

```
if(![yourTableView isEditing]){
  // Execute your code else not...
}
```